provide to a context based on consumed property in lit
Lit Playground Example
As showed in my lit playground example, I want to pass a consumed context to provide a new context. But at the time of defining other properties, the consumed property is undefined. In the connected callback or the render method, the consumed property is available.
This example is minimal for showcase. In a more complex scenario, I want to pass the consumed property as contructor parameter to the property which should be provided for possible other childs in the component tree. 
That's because my properties are no lit elements. They are service classes, which cannot read from the context without listening manually. Otherwise I would inject them directly in that service classes. Are there any suggestions?
@consume({context: aContext})
@property()
a!: String;
@provide({context: bContext})
@property()
b: String = this.a;

I can't be sure this is the cause but I recall that decorators had some timing issue like that and resorted to using the reactive controller classes directly for this: https://lit.dev/playground/#sample=examples/context-consume-provide See the my-section.ts file.

Thanks. Updating the provider within the consumer callback works. Still not very happy with that overhead code and because it looks technically not very well to assign those provider two times (one undefined, next with value). But at least functionality is given.
